# Trying to pass MPI derived types between processors (and failing)

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi, fortran90, derived-types

I am trying to parallelize a customer's Fortran code with MPI.  `f` is an array of 4-byte reals dimensioned `f(dimx,dimy,dimz,dimf)`.  I need the various processes to work on different parts of the array's first dimension.  (I would have rather started with the last, but it wasn't up to me.)  So I define a derived type `mpi_x_inteface` like so

```
call mpi_type_vector(dimy*dimz*dimf, 1, dimx, MPI_REAL,  &
                     mpi_x_interface, mpi_err)
call mpi_type_commit(mpi_x_interface, mpi_err)
```

My intent is that a single mpi_x_interface will contain all of the data in 'f' at some given first index "i".  That is, for given i, it should contain `f(i,:,:,:)`.  (Note that at this stage of the game, all procs have a complete copy of `f`.  I intend to eventually split `f` up between the procs, except I want proc 0 to have a full copy for the purpose of gathering.)

`ptsinproc` is an array containing the number of "i" indices handled by each proc.  `x_slab_displs` is the displacement from the beginning of the array for each proc.  For two procs, which is what I am testing on, they are  `ptsinproc=(/61,60/)`, `x_slab_displs=(/0,61/)`.  `myminpt` is a simple integer giving the minimum index handled in each proc.

So now I want to gather all of `f` into proc 0 and I run

```
    if (myrank == 0) then
      call mpi_gatherv(MPI_IN_PLACE, ptsinproc(myrank),
 +                     mpi_x_interface, f(1,1,1,1), ptsinproc,
 +                     x_slab_displs, mpi_x_interface, 0,
 +                     mpi_comm_world, mpi_err)
    else
      call mpi_gatherv(f(myminpt,1,1,1), ptsinproc(myrank),
 +                     mpi_x_interface, f(1,1,1,1), ptsinproc,
 +                     x_slab_displs, mpi_x_interface, 0,
 +                     mpi_comm_world, mpi_err)
    endif
```

I can send at most one "slab" like this.  If I try to send the entire 60 "slabs" from proc 1 to proc 0 I get a seg fault due to an "invalid memory reference".  BTW, even when I send that single slab, the data winds up in the wrong places.

I've checked all the obvious stuff like maiking sure myrank and ptsinproc and x_slab_dislps are what they should be on all procs.  I've looked into the difference between "size" and "extent" and so on, to no avail.  I'm at my wit's end.  I just don't see what I am doing wrong.  And someone might remember that I asked a similar (but different!) question a few months back.  I admit I'm just not getting it.  Your patience is appreciated.

Comment: The fixed is the old code I am working in.  The free form is from a new file I have created myself.

Comment: If you are using `OPENMPI` implementation of `MPI`, make sure you have the latest version possible or at least version greater than `1.8.5`. There has been a lot of issues with `MPI_IN_PLACE` in `OPENMPI`. You can check https://www.open-mpi.org/source/new.php and search for `MPI_IN_PLACE` to see the number of time there has been a fix for problems related to `MPI_IN_PLACE`. A simple check will be to replace `MPI_IN_PLACE` by the actual buffer.

Comment: @innoSPG When I make the substitution, I get failure with another error: "Buffers must not be aliased"  Does that reveal anything?  But actually, I'm using MPICH.

Comment: If you are already using MPICH, the problem is somewhere else. Possibly in the data type matching. I am not a big user of MPI user data type. What I usually do in such situation is to reshape the array to have the right ordering. Of course, I do that when memory is not a big issue. Because it requires two copy of the large array at some point in time.

Comment: I know it's not answering your question, but you should really really not name your own functions and variables starting with `mpi_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I just want to say that the reason you're running into so many problems is because you are trying to split up the first (fastest) axis. This is not recommended at all because as-is packing your `mpi_x_interface` requires a lot of non-contiguous memory accesses. We're talking a huge loss in performance.

Splitting up the slowest axis across MPI processes is a much better strategy. I would highly recommend transposing your 4D matrix so that the `x` axis is last if you can.

Now to your actual problem(s)...

**Derived datatypes**

As you have deduced, one problem is that the size and extent of your derived datatype might be incorrect. Let's simplify your problem a bit so I can draw a picture. Say `dimy*dimz*dimf=3`, and `dimx=4`. As-is, your datatype `mpi_x_interface` describes the following data in memory:

```
| X |   |   |   | X |   |   |   | X |   |   |   |
```

That is, every 4th `MPI_REAL`, and 3 of them total. Seeing as this is what you want, so far so good: the size of your variable is correct. However, if you try and send "the next" `mpi_x_interface`, you see that your implementation of MPI will start at the next point in memory (which in your case has not been allocated), and throw an "invalid memory access" at you:

```
                                             tries to access and bombs
                                                 vvv
| X |   |   |   | X |   |   |   | X |   |   |   | Y |   |   |   | Y | ...
```

What you need to tell MPI as part of your datatype is that "the next" `mpi_x_interface` starts only 1 `real` into the array. This is accomplished by redefining the "extent" of your derived datatype by calling [`MPI_Type_create_resized()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Type_create_resized.3.php). In your case, you need to write

```
integer :: mpi_x_interface, mpi_x_interface_resized
integer, parameter :: SIZEOF_REAL = 4 ! or whatever f actually is

call mpi_type_vector(dimy*dimz*dimf, 1, dimx, MPI_REAL,  &
                 mpi_x_interface, mpi_err)
call mpi_type_create_resized(mpi_x_interface, 0, 1*SIZEOF_REAL, &
                             mpi_x_interface_resized, mpi_err)
call mpi_type_commit(mpi_x_interface_resized, mpi_err)
```

Then, calling "the next" 3 `mpi_x_interface_resized` will result in:

```
| X | Y | Z | A | X | Y | Z | A | X | Y | Z | A |
```

as expected.

**MPI_Gatherv**

Note that now you have correctly defined the extent of your datatype, calling `mpi_gatherv` with an offset in terms of your datatype should now work as expected.

Personally, I wouldn't think there is a need to try some fancy logic with `MPI_IN_PLACE` for a collective operation. You can simply set `myminpt=1` on `myrank==0`. Then you can call on every rank:

```
   call mpi_gatherv(f(myminpt,1,1,1), ptsinproc(myrank),
+                     mpi_x_interface_resized, f, ptsinproc,
+                     x_slab_displs, mpi_x_interface_resized, 0,
+                     mpi_comm_world, mpi_err)
```

Comment: " ... the reason you're running into so many problems is because you are trying to split up the first (fastest) axis."  You are exactly right, but like I said, it's not my decision.  Thanks for your answer.  Am looking it over.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you!  So the idea, then, is that left to itself, MPI will think that the location of the next element to be sent is the memory location "right at the end" of the first element (ignoring complications like padding).  I wanted MPI to go construct the second element by starting 4 bytes after the beginning of my first element, but I had to explain that to MPI.  Sound right?  Thanks again.

Comment: @bob.sacamento Yes that's it exactly. The extent of the derived datatype is by default set to be the size of the derived datatype. In your case, you wanted to change the extent to only be 4 bytes, but keep the size the same.